# How to sum a column pending on the occurence of the column to another column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to sum the no_of_votes of every candidates in a state or in a voting centre..
so if i have two candidates that they occur more than once, i want to get the sum of each candidates votes in the state.
This is my query

```
$election = $this->election
            ->where('position_title_id', 1)
            ->whereYear('election_date', now())
            ->first();

            $vote_result = DB::table('elections')
            ->join('election_ward', 'elections.id', '=', 'election_ward.election_id')
            ->join('election_ward_candidate', 'election_ward.id', '=', 'election_ward_candidate.election_ward_id')
            ->join('voting_centres', 'election_ward.voting_centre_id', '=', 'voting_centres.id')
            ->join('wards', 'wards.id', '=', 'voting_centres.ward_id')
            ->join('cities', 'cities.id', '=', 'wards.city_id')
            ->join('states', 'states.id', '=', 'cities.state_id')
            ->join('candidates', 'candidates.id', '=', 'election_ward_candidate.candidate_id')

            ->select
            (
             'states.*','election_ward_candidate.*','candidates.*',
            // DB::raw('sum(no_of_votes) as candidates_vote, election_ward_candidate.election_ward_id'), 
            // DB::raw('max(no_of_votes) as ward_votes, election_ward_candidate.candidate_id'), 

            )
            // ->groupBy('election_ward_candidate.election_ward_id')
            ->where('elections.id', $election->id)
            ->orderBy('states.name', 'asc')
            // ->orderBy('candidates_vote', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

and this is my response

```
[
    {
        "id": "01gssmzgpewx36gx31g1mqx5e0",
        "country_id": 160,
        "name": "Abia",
        "abbr": "Abia",
        "is_active": 1,
        "created_at": "2023-02-21 09:30:52",
        "updated_at": "2023-02-21 09:30:52",
        "election_ward_id": 1,
        "candidate_id": "01gssmzgpewx36gx31g1mqx5e0",
        "no_of_votes": "12",
        "meta": null,
        "gender": "Male",
        "full_name": "Senate 1",
        "running_mate_name": "Benjamin recious",
        "user_id": null,
        "position_title_id": 1,
        "state_id": null,
        "political_party_id": 2,
        "mandate_form": null,
        "status": "review",
        "election_id": "01gsr75bpc1cx8423zdk8nrv0x"
    },
    {
        "id": "01gssmzyzk8kkc8f6esbqknt15",
        "country_id": 160,
        "name": "Abia",
        "abbr": "Abia",
        "is_active": 1,
        "created_at": "2023-02-21 09:31:07",
        "updated_at": "2023-02-21 09:31:07",
        "election_ward_id": 1,
        "candidate_id": "01gssmzyzk8kkc8f6esbqknt15",
        "no_of_votes": "13",
        "meta": null,
        "gender": "Male",
        "full_name": "Senate 2",
        "running_mate_name": "Benjamin recious",
        "user_id": null,
        "position_title_id": 1,
        "state_id": null,
        "political_party_id": 1,
        "mandate_form": null,
        "status": "review",
        "election_id": "01gsr75bpc1cx8423zdk8nrv0x"
    },
    {
        "id": "01gssmzgpewx36gx31g1mqx5e0",
        "country_id": 160,
        "name": "Abia",
        "abbr": "Abia",
        "is_active": 1,
        "created_at": "2023-02-21 09:30:52",
        "updated_at": "2023-02-21 09:30:52",
        "election_ward_id": 4,
        "candidate_id": "01gssmzgpewx36gx31g1mqx5e0",
        "no_of_votes": "10",
        "meta": null,
        "gender": "Male",
        "full_name": "Senate 1",
        "running_mate_name": "Benjamin recious",
        "user_id": null,
        "position_title_id": 1,
        "state_id": null,
        "political_party_id": 2,
        "mandate_form": null,
        "status": "review",
        "election_id": "01gsr75bpc1cx8423zdk8nrv0x"
    },
    {
        "id": "01gssmzyzk8kkc8f6esbqknt15",
        "country_id": 160,
        "name": "Abia",
        "abbr": "Abia",
        "is_active": 1,
        "created_at": "2023-02-21 09:31:07",
        "updated_at": "2023-02-21 09:31:07",
        "election_ward_id": 4,
        "candidate_id": "01gssmzyzk8kkc8f6esbqknt15",
        "no_of_votes": "9",
        "meta": null,
        "gender": "Male",
        "full_name": "Senate 2",
        "running_mate_name": "Benjamin recious",
        "user_id": null,
        "position_title_id": 1,
        "state_id": null,
        "political_party_id": 1,
        "mandate_form": null,
        "status": "review",
        "election_id": "01gsr75bpc1cx8423zdk8nrv0x"
    },
    {
        "id": "01gssmzgpewx36gx31g1mqx5e0",
        "country_id": 160,
        "name": "Adamawa",
        "abbr": "Adamawa",
        "is_active": 1,
        "created_at": "2023-02-21 09:30:52",
        "updated_at": "2023-02-21 09:30:52",
        "election_ward_id": 2,
        "candidate_id": "01gssmzgpewx36gx31g1mqx5e0",
        "no_of_votes": "14",
        "meta": null,
        "gender": "Male",
        "full_name": "Senate 1",
        "running_mate_name": "Benjamin recious",
        "user_id": null,
        "position_title_id": 1,
        "state_id": null,
        "political_party_id": 2,
        "mandate_form": null,
        "status": "review",
        "election_id": "01gsr75bpc1cx8423zdk8nrv0x"
    },
    {
        "id": "01gssmzyzk8kkc8f6esbqknt15",
        "country_id": 160,
        "name": "Adamawa",
        "abbr": "Adamawa",
        "is_active": 1,
        "created_at": "2023-02-21 09:31:07",
        "updated_at": "2023-02-21 09:31:07",
        "election_ward_id": 2,
        "candidate_id": "01gssmzyzk8kkc8f6esbqknt15",
        "no_of_votes": "15",
        "meta": null,
        "gender": "Male",
        "full_name": "Senate 2",
        "running_mate_name": "Benjamin recious",
        "user_id": null,
        "position_title_id": 1,
        "state_id": null,
        "political_party_id": 1,
        "mandate_form": null,
        "status": "review",
        "election_id": "01gsr75bpc1cx8423zdk8nrv0x"
    },
    {
        "id": "01gssmzgpewx36gx31g1mqx5e0",
        "country_id": 160,
        "name": "Adamawa",
        "abbr": "Adamawa",
        "is_active": 1,
        "created_at": "2023-02-21 09:30:52",
        "updated_at": "2023-02-21 09:30:52",
        "election_ward_id": 3,
        "candidate_id": "01gssmzgpewx36gx31g1mqx5e0",
        "no_of_votes": "16",
        "meta": null,
        "gender": "Male",
        "full_name": "Senate 1",
        "running_mate_name": "Benjamin recious",
        "user_id": null,
        "position_title_id": 1,
        "state_id": null,
        "political_party_id": 2,
        "mandate_form": null,
        "status": "review",
        "election_id": "01gsr75bpc1cx8423zdk8nrv0x"
    },
    {
        "id": "01gssmzyzk8kkc8f6esbqknt15",
        "country_id": 160,
        "name": "Adamawa",
        "abbr": "Adamawa",
        "is_active": 1,
        "created_at": "2023-02-21 09:31:07",
        "updated_at": "2023-02-21 09:31:07",
        "election_ward_id": 3,
        "candidate_id": "01gssmzyzk8kkc8f6esbqknt15",
        "no_of_votes": "11",
        "meta": null,
        "gender": "Male",
        "full_name": "Senate 2",
        "running_mate_name": "Benjamin recious",
        "user_id": null,
        "position_title_id": 1,
        "state_id": null,
        "political_party_id": 1,
        "mandate_form": null,
        "status": "review",
        "election_id": "01gsr75bpc1cx8423zdk8nrv0x"
    }
]
```

So, i want to be able to get the sum of each candidate in each state..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUM` and add `GROUP BY` :

```php
$election = $this->election
            ->where('position_title_id', 1)
            ->whereYear('election_date', now())
            ->first();

$vote_result = DB::table('elections')
            ->join('election_ward', 'elections.id', '=', 'election_ward.election_id')
            ->join('election_ward_candidate', 'election_ward.id', '=', 'election_ward_candidate.election_ward_id')
            ->join('voting_centres', 'election_ward.voting_centre_id', '=', 'voting_centres.id')
            ->join('wards', 'wards.id', '=', 'voting_centres.ward_id')
            ->join('cities', 'cities.id', '=', 'wards.city_id')
            ->join('states', 'states.id', '=', 'cities.state_id')
            ->join('candidates', 'candidates.id', '=', 'election_ward_candidate.candidate_id')
            ->select('states.*', 'candidates.*', DB::raw('SUM(election_ward_candidate.no_of_votes) as candidate_votes'))
            ->where('elections.id', $election->id)
            ->groupBy('states.id', 'candidates.id')
            ->orderBy('states.name', 'asc')
            ->get();
```

Comment: thanks very much....this works perfectly for what i want it to do...thanks so much

Comment: but what if i only want to get the candidates with the highest votes from each of the state

Comment: I think you can use a subquery that returns maximum vote count for each state, and then join that subquery with `elections` table on the state and vote count